# Awesome WM: master windows count

Tags: linux, awesome-wm

Im just start using Awesome WM. Everything looks great especially multihead for my secondary monitor, the only one confusing thing is count of master window count and count of columns for non-master windows. Everything is clear about idea how it should work however when time come to practice it`s quite hard, at least for me to understand how much master windows do I have, because of this some features like increasing/decreasing main window start working unexpectedly.... So I was looking at Awesome Wiki and Google with no luck, about how to find count of columns and master windows from terminal (or even better a widget to show count of master windows at particular tag)?

Answer (score 0):

If you'r working with the regular rc.lua then you should have 1 master Window and the rest all non-master windows. The master Window is usually the most recently *opened* window. If you focus another widow your master window will remain still the one which you have opened last.

Given you have 1 Master window and a number of non-master windows. You can perform Three different things.

- You can exchange the master window for any of the non-master windows
- You can declare one of the non-master windows an additional master status. Now you have 2 Master windows
- You can revoke the master status from your master window. Now you have only non-master windows.

Note that the rules and counts for master windows are individual to each different tag. so if you go to another tag you will have to rearrange the numbers of master and non-master windows.

Comment: The theory sounds good, but in practice how do you know which windows are master or not? There is no visual indicator, you've to rely on your own memory, it's not usable. Do you know if there is a widget to display the master count and the column count? Or a visual highlight do differentiate windows?

P.s: sorry for the necroposting :-)